# Best way to implement while loop in java 8 or later

Tags: java, performance

I have to remove all slash (/) from the beginning of string. 
So I have written

```
while (convertedUrl.startsWith("\\")) 
{
     convertedUrl = convertedUrl.substring(1);
}
```

Above code creates string for each substring.
Is there any better way to write this code in java 8 or later?
How can I do it keeping mind memory utilisation and performance.

Comment: Check this similar post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28741673/do-while-with-java8-optional

Comment: Your code handles ``\`` but in your question you claim you want to remove `/` so which is it?

Comment: Anyway what is the exact text you are handling and what you want to achieve? If it is some common task maybe using URI/URL classes would be easier?

Comment: Aside from that you could use regex like `convertedUrl = convertedUrl.replaceFirst("^\\\\+", "");` (if you want to remove series of ``\`` at beginning of string). Change ``\\\\`` to `/` if you want to remove `/`.

Comment: Keep in mind that you only need to optimize this for performance if you measure your program's performance and this is the bottleneck

Comment: @Pshemo it is \ in this case.  Actually I don't want to use substring method.

Comment: I am not suggesting you to use substring. But if you are handling strings like `/foo/bar/data.php?param1=x&param2=y` then URL or URI are most often good enough for handling usual tasks like extracting some pars of it. But since we don't know what you really want to achieve we can't help you with that. In other words it looks like yet another case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 4):

I would guess at:

```
 int len = str.length();
 int i=0;
 for (; i<len && str.charAt(i) == '\\'; ++i) {
      ;
 }
 return str.substring(i);
```

I write `str` instead of `convertedUrl` because this should be in its own method.

It is unlikely this is a performance bottleneck, but the original code may run as slow as O(n^2) (depending on implementation).

Answer (score -1):

can you simply not use something like this, to replace all the "/" in one go

```
convertedUrl = convertedUrl.replaceAll("\\/","");
```

I am sorry for the initial one, but I think this will do:

```
convertedUrl = convertedUrl.replaceFirst("^/*","");
```

OR this:

```
convertedUrl = convertedUrl.replaceAll("^/*","");
```

both will get the job done!
as they replaces all the leading "/" chars!

Comment: That would replace all `/` in string. Not what OP wants (at least according to his code).

Comment: Also you don't need to escape `/` in Java regex since it doesn't use `/regex/flags` syntaks which makes `/` special, but plain `regex` where `/` doesn't have any special meaning.